# Typescript writing zip function type declaration for any number of parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I wrote an iterator class and a method for zipping two iterators which takes 1 argument and its type declaration looks like this:

```
zip<B>(other: Iterable<B> | Iterator<B>): ItIterator<[T, B]>
```

where `T` is the type of `this.next().value`.

However I can't grasp how to write it so it takes any number of arguments and returns an iterator over a tuple such that

```
ItIterator.prototype.zip.call([1][Symbol.iterator](), ['a'], [false])
```

would return `ItIterator<[number, string, boolean]>`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrDraW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah, this is perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the approach I'd take:

```
declare class ItIterator<T> {
  zip<B extends any[]>(
    ...other: { [I in keyof B]: Iterable<B[I]> | Iterator<B[I]> }
  ): ItIterator<[T, ...B]>;
}
```

The idea is that `zip()` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `B`, the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of the element types of the `other` iterables.  I mean that if you call `zip(x, y, z)` where `x` is an `Iterable<X>`, `y` is an `Iterable<Y>`, and `z` is an `Iterable<Z>`, then the type argument `B` will be `[X, Y, Z]`.

This is accomplished by having the [rest parameter tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) of `other` be a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) over `B`.

Then the output type is an `ItIterator<>` of the [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) `[T, ...B]`, where we prepend `T` to the tuple of `B`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
declare const i: ItIterator<string>;

const y = i.zip([1], [true], [new Date(), new Date()]);
// const y: ItIterator<[string, number, boolean, Date]>
```

Looks good.  Note that I wouldn't try to support

```
const z = ItIterator.prototype.zip.call([1][Symbol.iterator](), ['a'], [false]);
// const z: ItIterator<[any, ...any[]]>
```

because [the typing support for the `call()` method of functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#strictbindcallapply) does not work well with functions that are themselves generic, and you end up getting just the constraint of `ItIterator<[any, ...any[]]>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwJIBcshlTA9jADwAqAfPAN4BQ88AXgJYAOxAQvCAB6YgB2wNFH4BPANoBdcgAo69eADplBTAAtcALmrxx6eE37wA1iFEEAZvHaTtOPACMIIDnunwAPhj55CJdm6UAL7yAJR22D74RMTipAA0Sso25ADcNCE0oEhwiAT8yJgGEfbRJIUwhgDmaTQ0YPmF8KLwALwGiswsMuIAjJKJ4pgwAK4gA7r8IADu8AAi+CAyoYlTswt8y5Kh6QD0u3kFRaIlUX6xFdWrIwC2DriJDgQEziKJG+PkdQ1HjG3epT8ihYMFUqlELBAnVYijAUAgEB6-XEAGVRHcXoomGciJJloMAORQAkTcQWeHIcY7Gj7Q5NBinXBlWIiUSJZSKVlSaRAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot, without the explanation this legitimately looked like black magic to me